# liquidfun 1.1.0 ndk-build 2 compile errors

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ndk-build, liquidfun

Alright, I'm trying to build liquidfun for the first time and I'm having trouble getting past compilation errors. I'm not to savvy with c/c++ so I'm not sure how to get these fixed so I can build.

The error is...

> [armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm  : liquidfun <= b2ParticleSystem.cpp
>   jni/../Box2D/Particle/b2ParticleSystem.cpp:2734:2: error: ignoring return value
>        of function declared with warn_unused_result attribute
>        [-Werror,-Wunused-result]
>          std::remove_if(m_bodyContactBuffer.Begin(),
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   1 error generated.
>   make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/liquidfun/Box2D/Particle/b2ParticleSystem.o] Error 1

I was able to find a solution for a shifting error that I encountered, but unfortunately nothing on this issue. I was hoping someone could help me get this thing built so I can start playing with this engine.

A bit more details

> LiquidFun version: 1.1.0
>   Build instructions: [LiquidFun Build instructions for android](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/Building/html/md__building_android.html)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this searching for answers on Github. The warn_result_error can be resolved by adding (void) at the beginning of line 2734:

```
(void)std::remove_if(m_bodyContactBuffer.Begin(),
```

Source: https://github.com/google/liquidfun/issues/70